# Find $a$ such that $L$ becomes a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Given the vectors:
>
> $$v_1 = (1, a, a^2), \ \ \ v_2 = (a^2, a, a^2), \ \ \ v_3 = (a, a^2, 1)$$
>
> Find what values of $a$ make $L: R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ become a linear transformation so that:
>
> $$v_1, v_2 \in ker(L)$$
>
> $$L(v_3) = (1, 1, 1)$$

For $L$ to be a linear transformation, I know that the following condition must be satisfied:

$$L(\lambda_1v_1 + \lambda_2v_2 + \lambda_3v_3) = \lambda_1L(v_1) + \lambda_2L(v_2) + \lambda_3L(v_3)$$

I also know the definition of ker. The ker of $L$ is:

$$Ker L = [v \in R^3 | L(v) = 0]$$

But I do not know how to even start. Could you give me a hint?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT 0**

As suggested by Fimpellizieri, I found for what values of $a$ are $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ linearly independent.

So I row-reduced the matrix constructed out of the given vectors.

$$A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & a & a^2 \\
    a^2 & 1 & a \\
    a & a^2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\sim \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & a & a^2 \\
    0 & 1-a^3 & a-a^4 \\
    0 & 0 & 1-a^3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus we see that $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly independent $\forall a$ \ $a=1$

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to Fimpellizieri for pointing my mistake out. The values for $a$ do not change though:

$$A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & a & a^2 \\
    a^2 & a & a^2 \\
    a & a^2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\sim \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & a & a^2 \\
    0 & a-a^2 & a^2-a^4 \\
    0 & 0 & 1-a^3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus we see that $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are linearly independent $\forall a$ \ $a=1$

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to Fimpellizieri I realized that I missed a value for $a$ that makes $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ not to be linearly independent: $a=0$.

OK so I picked the value $a=-1$. Solving for $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ one gets:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 1 \\
    0 & -2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    c_1 \\
    c_2 \\
    c_3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}=0$$

Thus $c_1 = c_2 = c_3= 0$

**EDIT 3**

Thanks to Fimpellizieri I realized that I did I mistake in my computation. Now it is correct:

$$A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & a & a^2 \\
    a^2 & a & a^2 \\
    a & a^2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\sim \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & a & a^2 \\
    0 & a-a^3 & a^2-a^4 \\
    0 & 0 & 1-a^3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus $a=0$, $a=1$ and $a=-1$ make $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ linearly dependent.

Alright, so any $u\in\Bbb R^3$ can be written as a linear combination of a basis spanning $\Bbb R^3$ (let me pick, for instance, $a = 2$):

$$u = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
    c_1 \\
    c_1 \\
    c_1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}(1, 2, 4) + \begin{pmatrix}
    c_2 \\
    c_2 \\
    c_2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}(4, 2, 4) + \begin{pmatrix}
    c_3 \\
    c_3 \\
    c_3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}(2, 4, 1)$$

Thus the matrix $L$ representing the linear transformation relative to the basis $\{(1, 2, 4),(4, 2, 4),(2, 4, 1)\}$ is:

$$L =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
    c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
    c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Based on the given conditions:

$$v_1, v_2 \in ker(L) \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$L(v_3) = (1, 1, 1) \ \ \ \ (2)$$

One gets the coefficients:

- Out of $(1)$:

$$c_1 = c_2 = 0$$

- Out of $(2)$:

$$L(v_3)= \begin{pmatrix}
    c_3 \\
    c_3 \\
    c_3 \\
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

$$c_3 = 1$$

Comment: Is there some information missing? (Like a definition of $L$?)

Comment: Try substituting your vectors into the equation you're given then use the three given values of $L$ at $v_1, v_2$ and $ v_3$ to establish a set of three equations with three unknown lambdas. Solve for the lambdas and see what that implies about the values of $a$ that make this transformation do what's required.

Comment: @angryavian I am only given the following info related to the linear transformation: $L(v_3) = (1, 1, 1)$ and $L: R^3 \rightarrow R^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not seem much too clear to me, because one speaks of kernels only with regards to linear transformations in the first place.

Besides, there's nothing about the definition of $L$ in the statement.
If you interpret it literally, all the question tells you about $L$ is that it's some function $\Bbb R^3 \mapsto \Bbb R^3$ and the values it takes on $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$.
The $v_i$ depend on $a$, but varying $a$ tells you nothing of the properties of $L$.
One can cook up just about any function satisfying $L(v_1)=L(v_2)= 0$ and $L(v_3) = (1,1,1)$ if no other requirements are made.

---

Trying to make sense of it, one could answer the following question:
for what values of $a$ is there a unique linear transformation $L:\Bbb R^3 \longrightarrow \Bbb R^3$ which satisfies the given conditions?

If $V = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly independent, then any $u\in\Bbb R^3$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$.
By the linearity of $L$, this means that $L$ is wholly defined by the values it takes on $V$.
In other words, it would be enough to find out when $V$ is linearly independent and when it is not (in terms of $a$).
Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found the values of $a$ such that the three vectors are linearly independent(please see my edit). You say we can just cook it up given $L(v_1)=L(v_2)= 0$ and $L(v_3) = (1,1,1)$ , but how?

Comment: Your row reduction does not look correct. Is $v_2$ written correctly?

Comment: Given $v\in\Bbb R^3$, find the unique $c_1,c_2,c_3\in\Bbb R$ with $v= c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$ and then $L(v) = c_1L(v_1)+c_2L(v_2)+c_3L(v_3)$ by linearity of $L$. Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are in the kernel, we can them simplify it to $L(v) = c_3L(v_3) = (c_3,c_3,c_3)$.

Comment: I've corrected the mistake. in EDIT 1. So now, if I am not mistaken, I should plug any value of $a$ I want (except $a=1$) into the given vectors and then solve for $c_1,c_2,c_3\in\Bbb R$. Next I should also verify $L(v) = c_3L(v_3) = (c_3,c_3,c_3)$ and then we are done. Is that what you meant? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to verify that, this will be automatic. There are still some values of $a$ you are missing, though.

Comment: Thanks; I missed $a=0$. So I get the trivial solution $c_1 = c_2 = c_3= 0$ (EDIT 2). Note that it is the unique solution of the system (it doesn't depend on the allowed value of $a$ we pick). Indeed, as $c_3 = 0$, the property $L(v) = c_3L(v_3) = (c_3,c_3,c_3)$ is automatically verified. Is that what you meant? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really follow you here. $a=-1,0,1$ are the values that make $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ linearly dependent.

Comment: My mistake, thanks for pointing it out (now fixed). I think I got your idea in EDIT 3. Please let me know if that is not what you meant and I'll be glad to keep working on it.